# Why do some Ex commands not need a white space before a path argument?

Tags: command-line, ex-mode, whitespace, filenames

For example, why does this work:

```
edit/home/foo/bar.txt
```

(I had to enter `visual` to see the changes)

I was expecting a whitespace after `edit`, like:

```
edit /home/foo/bar.txt
```

I couldn't find a reference in the docs.

Comment: Probably for convenience.  Vim is an interactive text editor; people want to perform their goals in the smallest amount of keypresses.  So, in Vim script legacy, it is allowed for a command name to be immediately followed by an argument whose first character can't be part of the latter; e.g. `:e#`, `:w/tmp/tt`.  Note that this is [no longer allowed in Vim9 script](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7467#issuecomment-744009258).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4):

I can't remember if it's documented anywhere, but Vim's parser skips over alphabetical characters ([`isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha)) to find commands' end. Hence `:edit/foo/bar/baz.txt` works okay.

In fact, the whole story is more complicated, as there are numerous exceptions to this rule. The relevant source code is [somewhere around this line](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/cff40ff98664f4f5a9631aff1a155caf762ea74b/src/ex_docmd.c#L3460).